# Bold citation number

Tags: formatting, citing, bold

Is there a straightforward way to produce bold citation numbers with the `\cite` command (I'm using amsplain bibliography style)? Essentially I want something like this: [**1**] rather than [1].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're not using any packages that modify `\cite`: The `\@cite@ofmt` macro is responsible for the typeset form of the citations; its default definition is `\hbox`. Changing it to `\bfseries\hbox` seems to have the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@cite@ofmt}{\bfseries\hbox}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: If you're using the [cite](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package, `\renewcommand{\citeform}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` does the trick.