# Highlight select citations by a modified citation mark

Tags: bibtex, citing

In a document I would like to denote some citations by a special citation mark, for example by adding an asterisk to the citation number. I am using the `article` document class and the `unsrturl` bibliography style, together with the `cite` package using the `superscript` option. Ideally I would also like to be able to add a note at the beginning of the bibliography section that describes the meaning of the asterisk. I am using bibtex to build the bibliography.

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

It does not matter wether the special citations would be marked by an entry in the .bib file or by using a special version of the `\cite` command.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266599/biblatex-highlight-self-references) seems to contain a solution to this problem but it seems to be specific to a bibliography style. I also do not know if using the `cite` package would require a different solution.

My latex file has the following general structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{citation1, TITLE = {A regular citation}}
 @article{citation2, TITLE = {A special citation}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\cite{citation1} and a special citation~\cite{citation2}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrturl}  
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Where do I go from here?

---

### Update

As an ugly workaround I have come up with the following (partial) solution: I define a special `\bibitem` command that replaces the label (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145169/162773) answer) and redefine `\refname` to squeeze the extra line of text under the **References** heading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite} 

\newcommand{\mybibitem}[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv} \bibitem[{\arabic{enumiv}*}]{#1}}

\renewcommand{\refname}{References

\noindent{\normalsize\rmfamily\mdseries {Note: Special citations are marked with an asterisk.}}
}

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\cite{citation1} and a special citation~\cite{citation2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{citation1} A regular citation.
\mybibitem{citation2} A special citation.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

This is getting close to what I want, but there are (at least) two problems:

1. I have to convert the `\bibitem` to `\mybibitem` in the .bbl for the special citations by hand, which is not ideal but workable for now.
2. The label of the special citation (2*) seems to be left-justified, rather than right-justified, which does not work for me because I have long list of references and therefore a rather wide column reserved for the labels. I have tried to right-justify the label using `\hfill` but that did not work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the alignment of those labels?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DG' I didn't include a MWE because I don't quite know where to start. I have added a basic template of the structure of my latex file that I hope will be helpful.

Comment: are you open to `biblatex` or do you have to use `cite`?

Comment: I would prefer a solution based on `cite` and `bibtex`.

Comment: That being said, a solution based on a different package (`biblatex` or `natbib`?) would also be helpful as long as it supports superscript numerical labels and does not require any changes to the .bib file.

Comment: What determines whether a citation is 'special' or not? The input is the same - does this depend on something about the content of the `.bib` entry or something else?

Comment: "Special" entries could either be marked in the .bib file, or I could use a "special" version of the $\cite$ command for those, something like   `In the main text there is a citation~\cite{citation1} and a special citation~\specialcite{citation2}`

Answer (score 8):

With `biblatex` that is fairly simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{citation1, TITLE = {A regular citation}}
 @article{citation2, TITLE = {A special citation}, keywords={special}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, autocite=superscript, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  #1%
  \ifkeyword{special}{*}{}%
}

\defbibnote{astnote}{Special citations are marked with an asterisk.}

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\autocite{citation1} and a special citation~\autocite{citation2}.

\printbibliography[prenote=astnote]
\end{document}
```

In this example, special entries are marked as such using the `special` keyword in the `.bib` file. If you prefer a more dynamic approach, you can use categories.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{citation1, TITLE = {A regular citation}}
 @article{citation2, TITLE = {A special citation}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, autocite=superscript, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{special}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  #1%
  \ifcategory{special}{*}{}%
}

\addtocategory{special}{citation2}

\defbibnote{astnote}{Special citations are marked with an asterisk.}

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\autocite{citation1} and a special citation~\autocite{citation2}.

\printbibliography[prenote=astnote]
\end{document}
```

Naturally you could combine the two

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  #1%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{special}}
              or test {\ifcategory{special}}}
    {*}{}%
}
```

It would also be possible to use a special cite command, but I strongly prefer the two methods shown here. When you cite, you should not have to worry whether or not a reference is special or not.

[image]

---

Since `biblatex` is different from BibTeX-based bibliography and citation management there are going to be some differences. Have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) for a comparison of the systems and general advice on switching to `biblatex`. You will also want to use Biber, so [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) might be worth a read.

In general a `.bib` file for BibTeX can also be used for `biblatex`, though `biblatex` can benefit from using certain fields that are not available for most BibTeX styles (remember: the `.bst` file ultimately decides which fields are supported and what exactly they mean and even though there is wide consensus among `.bst` files for many common fields, you can't always be sure that all styles make exactly the same thing from your data).

`biblatex`'s `numeric` standard style does not exactly look like `unsrturl`/`unsrt`. [`biblatex-trad`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad)'s `trad-unsrt` would probably be a closer match. But if you are OK with the general output that `style=numeric` gives (give or take a few simple modifications, [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)) I would not bother with `biblatex-trad` and stick with `style=numeric`. (I think I'm allowed to say that being the current maintainer of `biblatex-trad`.)

---

Here is a BibTeX solution. It requires hacking the `.bst` file as well as fiddling with internal macros of `thebibliography`.

To hack the `.bst` file you can either get the ready-made `unsrturl-special` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/727b429da91f9453639c0ec2fbdc17c2 (where you can also find the diff to the unmodified `unsrturl.bst`) or follow the steps below

1. Locate `unsrturl.bst` on your machine for example by typing `kpsewhich unsrturl.bst`, failing that download it from http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/unsrturl.bst
2. Copy the file to a place where LaTeX can find it (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf), the directory of your document will do just fine, and **rename** it to `unsrturl-special.bst`, say. Note that the license of `unsrt.bst` on which `unsrturl.bst` is based requires you to change the name of the file if you modify it.
3. Open `unsrturl-special.bst` and insert a header with the new file name and the current date
4. Add `special` to the list of known fields in `ENTRY` (around line 55)
5. Replace the entire `FUNCTION {output.bibitem.original}` with

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem.original} % urlbst (renamed from output.bibitem, so it can be wrapped below)
   { newline$
     "\bibitem" write$
     special empty$
       'skip$
       { "[" special * "]" * write$ }
     if$
     "{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}" write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
   }
   ```

   The block starting from `special empty$` to `if$` is new.
6. Replace `FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}` with

   ```
   FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
   { number.label int.to.str$
     special empty$
       'skip$
       { special * }
     if$
     'label :=
     number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
     label width$ longest.label.width >
       { label 'longest.label :=
         label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
       }
       'skip$
     if$
   }
   ```

   The block starting from `special empty$` to `if$` is new.
7. Save the file.

The diff is

```
--- unsrturl.bst    2011-07-20 12:00:29.000000000 +0200
+++ unsrturl-special.bst    2018-07-10 09:21:13.297153700 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,10 @@
+%%%%% unsrturl-special (2018-07-10)
+%%%%% unsrturl with support for marking special entries with an arbitrary
+%%%%% marker
+%%%%% The marker is given verbatim in the `special' field
+%%%%%
+%%%%% Original copyright notices follow
+
 %%% Modification of BibTeX style file /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/unsrt.bst
 %%% ... by urlbst, version 0.7 (marked with "% urlbst")
 %%% See <http://purl.org/nxg/dist/urlbst>
@@ -46,6 +53,7 @@
     pubmed % urlbst
     url % urlbst
     lastchecked % urlbst
+    special
   }
   {}
   { label }
@@ -251,7 +259,12 @@

 FUNCTION {output.bibitem.original} % urlbst (renamed from output.bibitem, so it can be wrapped below)
 { newline$
-  "\bibitem{" write$
+  "\bibitem" write$
+  special empty$
+    'skip$
+    { "[" special * "]" * write$ }
+  if$
+  "{" write$
   cite$ write$
   "}" write$
   newline$
@@ -1270,7 +1283,12 @@
 }

 FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
-{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
+{ number.label int.to.str$
+  special empty$
+    'skip$
+    { special * }
+  if$
+  'label :=
   number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
   label width$ longest.label.width >
     { label 'longest.label :=
```

In your document you now use `unsrturl-special` instead of `unsrturl` and modify an internal macro for `\bibitem` as shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{citation1, TITLE = {A regular citation}}
@article{citation2, TITLE = {A special citation}, special={*}}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\let\@olbibitem\@lbibitem
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
  \stepcounter{\@listctr}%
  \@olbibitem[\the\value{\@listctr}#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\cite{citation1} and a special citation~\cite{citation2}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrturl-special}  
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This requires you to add `special = {*}` to every bib entry you want to highlight with an asterisk. Of course you can use other special symbols there.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer; thank you very much. I ended up making the switch to biblatex, which after some initial hiccups seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is of any help but starting from your workaround in the update of your question I managed to automatically make the change the bbl file by adding an entry in the bib file and modifing the bst file.

Here your modified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite} 

\newcommand{\specialbibitem}[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv} \bibitem[{\arabic{enumiv}*}]{#1}}

\renewcommand{\refname}{References

\noindent{\normalsize\rmfamily\mdseries {Note: Special citations are marked with an asterisk.}}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{citation1, TITLE = {A regular citation}}
 @article{citation2, TITLE = {A special citation}, special = {*}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
In the main text there is a citation~\cite{citation1} and a special citation~\cite{citation2}.

\bibliographystyle{plain-special}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

Then you copy and rename the plain.bst file to plain-special.bst and

1. add the entry "special"

   ```
   ENTRY
     { address
       ...
       special
     }
   ```
2. replace the line `"\bibitem{" write$` in the FUNCTION {output.bibitem}

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
       { newline$
         special empty$ 
           { "\bibitem{" write$ }
           { "\specialbibitem{" write$ } 
         if$
         cite$ write$
         "}" write$
         newline$
         ""
         before.all 'output.state :=
       }`
   ```

Which gives:

[image]